# How will i get the echo out the second row in a column?

Tags: php, mysql, database

in database i have a attraction table, in the table i have 2 columns.
`image` and `num_of_days`

```
$image = "SELECT image FROM `attraction` WHERE num_of_days = 7";

$linkimage = mysqli_query($link, $image)or die(mysqli_error($link));

$displayimage = mysqli_fetch_array($linkimage);
```

it give me a list of photo in database. example

```
image1.jpg
image2.jpg
image3.jpg
```

when i call the image out

```
<img src="image/ < ?php echo $displayImage[0]; ?>" alt=""/>
```

Question is i want to select the `image2.jpg` instead of the first one

Comment: Why not update the where clause to select the correct record?

Comment: `SELECT image FROM \`attraction\` WHERE num_of_days = 7 LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1`

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try  `$displayImage[1]` instead of `$displayImage[0]`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Or you must loop over the `$displayImage` array to echo out all of them or in beginner-style use 3 lines with 0, 1 and 2 as the array index :

```
<img src="image/ < ?php echo $displayImage[0]; ?>" alt="1"/>
<img src="image/ < ?php echo $displayImage[1]; ?>" alt="2"/>
<img src="image/ < ?php echo $displayImage[2]; ?>" alt="3"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
   foreach($displayImage as $key=>$value){
      if($key == 2){
?>
<img src="image/<?php echo $value; ?>" alt="<?php $key; ?>"/>
<?php
      }
   }
?>
```

just change the key value to the row you want to show out.